# Laravel belongsToMany exclude pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent

I have two models, `User` and `Badge`. A user can have multiple badges, and a badge can belong to multiple users. (using a pivot table)

Currently I am getting the data I need, but additionally I am getting the `pivot` table along. How do I exclude this?

[image]

Here's the `User` model:

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    public function badges() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Badge', 'users_badges');
    }

}
```

And the `Badge` model:

```
class Badge extends Eloquent {

    public function users() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'users_badges');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Add `pivot` to your `$hidden` property's array in your model(s).

```
class Badge extends Eloquent {

    protected $hidden = ['pivot'];

    public function users() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'users_badges');
    }
}
```

And same with your `User` model

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    protected $hidden = ['pivot'];

    public function badges() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Badge', 'users_badges');
    }

}
```

Comment: @challet Yes, check out [the documentation here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json). Scroll a little bit down and you will find an example of how to dynamically hide attributes.

Comment: Note if you omit one model this will not work. You must hide the pivot on both related models.

Answer (score 41):

Or you can still **hide the pivot on demand** this way...

```
$user = User::find(1);
$user->badges->makeHidden('pivot');

$badge = Badge::find(1);
$badge->users->makeHidden('pivot');
```

Comment: `makeHidden` and `makeVisible` accept arrays as well: `makeHidden(['pivot', 'id', ...])` or `makeVisible(['pivot', 'id', ...])`

Comment: Please note that **makeHidden()** is a **Collection** method, it won't work on **Model.** It's a method of eloquent, not query builder.